# Exception thrown while running unit tests for maven plugin - ComponentLookupException :: NoSuchElementException :: RepositorySystem

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, maven-plugin

I'm trying to run unit tests to a Maven Plugin's Mojo using the artifact maven-plugin-testing-harness:3.3.0, with the following dependencies. But when I try to 'lookupEmptyMojo', the exception below is thrown. **Any quick way to solve this configuration issue?**

```
...
<properties>
  <maven.api.version>3.6.2</maven.api.version>
<dependencies>
<!-- Maven plugin deps -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
  <version>${maven.api.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
  <version>${maven.api.version}</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>

<!-- Tests -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.8.2</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-testing</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-plugin-testing-harness</artifactId>
  <version>3.3.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>
</dependencies>
...
```

Exception:

```
org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: java.util.NoSuchElementException
  role: org.apache.maven.repository.RepositorySystem
roleHint: 
at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:267)
...
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)

Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException
at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LocatedBeans$Itr.next(LocatedBeans.java:141)
... 28 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coming back to report how to had fixed this issue.

I had to add two others dependencies: maven-compat and maven-resolver-api.

Test-harness uses Maven2 classes, so if we are using Maven3 we need to add the lib maven-compat with the same version of maven api that we are using; this lib implements back compatibility with the old api.

RepositorySystem is an interface present in the maven-resolver-api lib, which works with artifact repositories, that can be remote, local, or even build reactor or IDE workspace.

The dependencies were added to the pom like the following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.resolver</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resolver-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compat</artifactId>
    <version>${maven.api.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```